# Getting graphs for linear inequalities

Tags: inequality

I am answering some activity on a book and the instructions is as follows:

> Graph the following inequalities and identify at least $3$ points that belong to the solution set of the inequalities.

So I went to get the graphing with the help of [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator/), but then:
[image: My Graphs]

This actually confused me. If I were to get $3$ points from the solution set of inequalities, I need to get both sides to intersect.

But this one is parallel, it won't intersect, so how can I get the solution set of inequalities if this is so?

> Try it, the 2 inequalities are:
>
> - $ y \ge 2x + 3 $
> - $ y < 2x - 4 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph correctly shows that there's no intersection for these two inequalities. There are no points that will solve them simultaneously.

We can also demonstrate the same thing algebraically. Given the two inequalities $y\ge 2x+3$ and $y<2x-4$, we can rewrite the intersection as

$$ 2x+3 \le y < 2x-4 . $$

So, any solution must have $ 2x+3 < 2x-4 $. But, notice, if you subtract $2x$ from both sides of this inequality, we have $3 < -4$. This is obviously not true, regardless of what values of $x$ and $y$ we choose, so there is no solution to this pair of inequalities.